# Transfer data from BigQuery to Teradata Vantage in GCP

Tags: google-bigquery, teradata

Is there any way to transfer data from Google BigQuery to Teradata Vantage on GCP. Can Google Data Fusion or Apache Nifi be used for this purpose?

Comment: This question is too general. Can it be done? Of course... Can you use Data Fusion or Nifi? Possibly. But for large volumes of data, any JDBC-based tools may not perform as well as you would like.

Comment: Thanks Fred..Just wanted to know if anyone has tried using these tools before.  We are looking to transfer data in batches.. Tried using Nifi and Data Fusion. Worked in both the cases.. Probably use one of them